# ¿Cómo funciona `i=~-i`?

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico, lógica

En una pregunta reciente en el sitio, se muestra un meme sobre ciertas expresiones en un lenguaje de programación y se pregunta cómo funciona una de ellas.

El meme era el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta era cómo funcionaba `i -=- 1`. Sin embargo, la que a mi me llamó verdaderamente la atención fue la última: `i = ~-i` ¿de verdad esto sirve para lo mismo que las anteriores, es decir, para incrementar `i` en 1?

Si es así ¿cómo funciona?

Comment: de donde cogiste el meme?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

En realidad la expresión está mal. Si la pruebas, por ejemplo en un intérprete Python, verás que no incrementa `i`, sino que la decrementa:

```
>>> i = 10
>>> i = ~-i
>>> i
9
```

Esto de todas formas ya es bastante misterioso ¿cómo es que se decrementa `i`?

La razón es que un cambio de signo está implementado en la arquitectura mediante lo que se llama "complemento a 2", y el operador `~` realiza un "complemento a 1". Ambas operaciones combinadas resultan en el decremento, según vamos a ver.

## Complemento a 2

La lógica detrás del "complemento a 2" es poder hacer restas usando la misma maquinaria que se tiene para hacer sumas. Imagina que tu CPU tiene solo 8 bits (en realidad tienen 32 o 64, pero vamos a mantener el ejemplo manejable), y por tanto los únicos números que puede manejar van de 0 a 255. Imagina también que esta CPU sólo sabe sumar (lo cual es bastante cercano a la realidad).

Ahora imagina que tenemos el número 2 y le queremos restar 1. Ya que la CPU sólo sabe sumar ¿cómo podríamos restar?

El truco es darse cuenta de que al tener solo 8 bits, si un resultado se pasa de 255, de alguna forma se "da la vuelta al marcador" y vuelve a empezar por cero. Así que si en lugar de restarle 1 al 2, le sumamos 255, el resultado sería 257, pero este no cabe en 8 bits. El bit sobrante (el más significativo) se descarta, y los restantes bits quedarían codificando el 1 (257-256).

En binario puede verse:

```java
  2: --> 00000010
255: --> 11111111
------------------
       1 00000001
```

El bit sobrante (acarreo) no forma parte de la respuesta, que sería `00000001`. Por tanto hemos sumado a 2 una cantidad y ha salido 1. Esa cantidad por tanto tiene que ser -1 ¿no? De modo que elegimos que el 255 represente en realidad el -1.

Esto puede hacerse para cualquier positivo N entre 1 y 127. Convertirlo en negativo cambiándolo por (256-N) y es lo que se llama "complemento a 2".

Así pues, el complemento a 2 de un número N es 256-N (en CPUs de 8 bits, en general, con M bits sería 2<sup>M</sup>-N).Y eso es lo que hace el operador `-` delante de un entero, obtener su complemento a 2.

De modo que `-i` calcula el complemento a 2 de `i`.

Resulta que hay otra forma más sencilla de calcular este complemento a 2 si lo vemos en binario. Vimos que el complemento a 2 del 1 era 255, lo que en binario se ve así:

```
dato:  00000001
C-2:   11111111
```

Si comparas ambos ves que el C-2 se ha obtenido cambiando todos los 0 por 1, excepto el último. En realidad hay una regla genaral de cómo calcularlo:

- Cambiar todos los 0 por 1 y todos los 1 por 0 (esto se llama "complemento a 1", o también "negación lógica", o "NOT")
- Sumar 1 al resultado

Este método vale para cualquier número, no sólo para el -1. Y para cualquier cantidad de bits.

## Explicación de la expresión

Y ya tenemos los ingredientes para saber cómo funciona la expresión:

```
i = ~-i
```

Primero, debido al `-i` se calcula el complemento a 2 de `i`, lo que consiste en cambiar todos los 1 por 0 y todos los 0 por 1, y finalmente sumar 1 al resultado.

Después, se aplica  `~` al resultado. Este operador hace la negación lógica, o "complemento a 1". Es decir, cambia todos los 1 por 0 y 0 por 1 de nuevo (salvo que luego no suma 1 al resultado).

Veamos cómo funciona suponiendo que `i` vale 10 (que en binario y con 8 bits es `00001010`)

```
Valor inicial  i:   00001010
Compl.2       -i:   11110110
Negación     ~-i:   00001001
```

Y resulta que lo que sale es 9, uno menos que el valor inicial.

## ¿Y si quiero incrementar?

Una vez comprendido el mecanismo, vemos que para incrementar basta usar esos mismos operadores pero en orden inverso:

```
i = -~i
```

Aquí es más fácil incluso explicar el funcionamiento:

- Primero se hace la negación lógica `~` que cambia los 1 por ceros y ceros por 1
- Después se hace el C-2 del resultado, que equivale a:

  - Hacer primero una negación lógica (con lo que vuelve a cambiarse 1 por 0 y 0 por 1 y el dato queda como estaba originalmente)
  - Sumar 1. ¡Por eso al final tenemos el dato incrementado!