# Uso del "Bitwise" - Python

Tags: python, operador

Se supone que ~ es el operador not a nivel binario.
Resulta que tengo el siguiente programa:

```
x = 4
y = 1

a = x & y
b = x | y
c = ~ x
d = x ^ 5
e = x >> 2
f = x << 2

print(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

Y me genera la siguiente salida:

```
0 5 **-5** 1 1 16
```

Esperaba que la salida fuera

```
0 5 **3** 1 1 16
```

En teoría 4 en binario = 100. Si lo niego debería ser igual a 011. Y eso es 3, no -5.
Me podrían explicar por favor por qué pasa eso.
Gracias

Comment: Revisa esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/315906/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-i-i/315907#315907)

Comment: `4` en binario no es `100`, sino `00000100` (eso con 8 bits, sigue rellenando con ceros a la izquierda para 16, 32, etc..) Al hacer la negación se convertirá por tanto en `11111011`. El hecho de que el primer bit sea un 1, ya le hace negativo. Para ver su valor debes hallar su complemento a 2 y verás que es el -5

Answer (score 2):

x es 4, que en binario sería 100.

~ x transforma cada '1' en '0' y viceversa, por lo que ~ x = 11 ... 11011 (un montón de unos y 011 al final).

Es un número negativo. Si le sumamos 5 (binario 101), el resultado es cero. Por tanto, el valor de ~ x es -5. Veamos la operación considerando sólo 8 bits:

```
  ~x 1111 1011
+  5 0000 0101
     ---------
     0000 0000
```